# Exclude parentType element from ChildType element in xsd

Tags: xsd

I have following two elements in my xsd. Both are related by extension. I am just wondering if it is possible that I remove/exclude one or more elements from ParentType when using it in ChildType. That means that though ChildType extends ParentType, it does not include all the elements from ParentType, Can I remove, say, element name="p3" type="boolean", from the ChildType?

```
<complexType name="ChildType">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="tns:ParentType">
            <sequence>
                <element name="a" type="boolean"/>
                <element name="b" type="string"/>
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>


<complexType name="ParentType" abstract="true">
    <sequence>
        <element name="p1" type="integer"/>
        <element name="p2" type="string"/>
        <element name="p3" type="boolean"/>         
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; if you want to remove some elements and add others, you will need two derivation steps:  one to restrict the type by eliminating some optional elements, and one to extend it by adding others at the end.

In this case, however, none of the elements of ParentType are optional, so no restrictions will be legal.  [Well, correction:  the only restrictions possible will be restrictions which assign smaller types to the elements p1, p2, or p3; no restrictions involving dropping any of those elements will be legal.]